# Set value in the second input based on the first input

Tags: jquery

I have two input fields in Wordpress Options Page. I am calculating the costs and then setting the value in the corresponding input field but it's setting in all of the second input. I want the value to be set only in the corresponding input field.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fzkLsmoy/)

```js
$('input[id^="calc_transport_"]').on('change', function() {
  var transport_margin_cost = getRandomNumber();
  $('input[id^="calc_m_transport_"]').val(transport_margin_cost.toFixed(2));
});

function getRandomNumber() {
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  return number;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="form-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_1" name="calc_transport_1" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_1" name="calc_m_transport_1" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_2" name="calc_transport_2" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_2" name="calc_m_transport_2" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_3" name="calc_transport_3" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_3" name="calc_m_transport_3" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">4 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_4" name="calc_transport_4" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_4" name="calc_m_transport_4" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">5 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_5" name="calc_transport_5" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_5" name="calc_m_transport_5" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all the elements that being with the `calc_m_transport_` id.

To solve this you can firstly use the classes on the elements to select them. From there you can use `$(this).siblings()` to find the `.transport-margin` element related to the one the user typed in. Try this:

```js
$('.transport').on('change', function() {
  var transport_margin_cost = getRandomNumber();
  $(this).siblings('.transport-margin').val(transport_margin_cost.toFixed(2));
});

function getRandomNumber() {
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  return number;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="form-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_1" name="calc_transport_1" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_1" name="calc_m_transport_1" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_2" name="calc_transport_2" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_2" name="calc_m_transport_2" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_3" name="calc_transport_3" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_3" name="calc_m_transport_3" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">4 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_4" name="calc_transport_4" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_4" name="calc_m_transport_4" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">5 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_5" name="calc_transport_5" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_5" name="calc_m_transport_5" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `next` and `this` to find next input. `next` only looks at the next sibling elemnet on the dom.

```
 $(this).next('input')
```

```js
   $('input[id^="calc_transport_"]').on('change', function() {
   var transport_margin_cost = getRandomNumber();
   $(this).next('input').val(transport_margin_cost.toFixed(2));
});

function getRandomNumber() {
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  return number;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="form-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_1" name="calc_transport_1" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_1" name="calc_m_transport_1" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_2" name="calc_transport_2" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_2" name="calc_m_transport_2" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_3" name="calc_transport_3" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_3" name="calc_m_transport_3" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">4 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_4" name="calc_transport_4" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_4" name="calc_m_transport_4" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">5 KG</th>
      <td>
        <input class="transport text" id="calc_transport_5" name="calc_transport_5" type="text" value="">
        <input class="transport-margin text" id="calc_m_transport_5" name="calc_m_transport_5" type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```